# Select last value and totalcount from joined table

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

I made two tables in my database;

- **todo_list**
- **todo_list_item**

Now,

The ***todo_list*** table contains

- *id*
- *name*

But has childs called list items, hence the 2nd table;

This table ***todo_list_item*** contains

- *id*
- *list_id*
- *name*
- *status_id*

What i'm trying to achieve, is:

1. Listing all **todo_list**s
2. Show how many **todo_list_item**s they contain
3. Get the last *status_id* from the **todo_list_item** table, per **todo_list**

Can i achieve this with one join, or do i really have to join the **todo_list_item** table twice, to get the count of items, and the last *status_id* seperately?

Comment: what do you means by "Get the last status_id from the todo_list_item table" How are you going to say status "XYZ" is last or latest?

Comment: @SMA When adding / updating a new todo_list_item, you can post a status. The real structure of the database is a bit more complicated, but the idea is that you can update todo items with a comment and a status. The last posted status will always be the 'current status' for that item.

Comment: "Can i achieve this with one join" - No.  "do i really have to join the todo_list_item table twice" - Yes. You'll probably even need a sub-query with a `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following which will get the `status` depending on the `max(id)` from `todo_list_item`

```
select 
td.*,
x.total,
tdi.status_id
from todo_list td
left join todo_list_item tdi on td.id = tdi.list_id 
join (
 select max(id) as id ,count(*) as total, list_id from todo_list_item group by list_id
)x
on x.id = tdi.id and x.list_id = tdi.list_id
```